# iOS prevent selection of entire paragraph on long press Vue JS touchhold event

Tags: javascript, css, ios, vue.js, safari

I'm using the [vue-touch-events `touchhold`](https://github.com/jerrybendy/vue-touch-events#v-touchtouchhold-v210) function to build a "peek" feature for a iOS & Android app that I'm working on, built using [Capacitor JS](https://capacitorjs.com/docs)

The app works well, but there doesn't seem to be a core plugin listed for creating a "peek" feature *(where the user long taps and then the phone vibrates and some text appears)*

I've got this part woking, but my issue is that on a physical device, on iOS, the long press (`touchhold`) event is triggering a selection of the text, that's the iOS selection box that's blue and allows a user to choose things such as: copy, paste etc...

I've added the following to my component that wraps the text and/or button that needs to be peeked:

```html
<template>
  <div
    unselectable="on"
    onselectstart="return false;"
    v-touch:touchhold="peek"
    onmousedown="return false;"
    class="tw-select-none">
    <slot name="activator"></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm using Tailwind CSS, but have tried the following:

- `user-select: none` is already applied
- `onmousedown` is set to return `false`
- `onselectstart` is set to return `false`
- `unselectable` is set to **on**
- I have some custom CSS for selections (which makes no difference) set as:

```css
::selection,
::-moz-selection,
::-webkit-selection {
    background: #000;
    color :#fff;
}
```

Despite all this, I still get the **annoying iOS selection box over everything**, how can I disable this? Or work around this? Maybe make it transparent somehow?